# vba find method doesnt work with cell with reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the VBA Find method on a column that uses the Excel Concatenate function on two other columns. It doesn't seem to be able to find a value that is displayed using the concatenate function, as when I just write in a value it finds it no problem. I am fairly new to VBA, so I'm not sure if there is just some nuance to using the Find method with references I am not aware of.
Edit:

```
CurrDevice = Range("B" & Target.Row)
CurrPort = Range("C" & Target.Row).Value
ConcatInfo = CurrDevice & CurrPort

Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = Range("R:R").Find(ConcatInfo)
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using so we can see the issue?

Comment: Is ConcatInfo present in the range? Check the value of concatinfo in the locals window when the error occurs.

Comment: `Range.Find` has an annoying "feature", in that it "remembers" the values for its optional parameters between calls. So you could have code that works fine, then you do Ctrl+F and tweak settings, re-run the same code, and it no longer works. It's safer to provide an explicit value for all optional parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the actual code you have, I assume the issue is that you are looking within the formula and not the value.  If you add this code to your find function it should work:

```
 Find( What , After , LookIn , LookAt , SearchOrder , SearchDirection , MatchCase , MatchByte , SearchFormat )
```

For the LookIn portion use this: `lookin:=xlValues`

Comment: Glad I could help :)